# Two algorithms in one latex document

Tags: algorithms

I want to use two different styles of algorithms with different latex packages `algorithm2e` and `algorithm`, but haven't succeeded. They work separately but not together.

One is:

```
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e} 

\newsavebox\mybox
\begin{algorithm}
\LinesNumbered
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\small
\State \t1  x: one Int,
\State \t1  y: one Int \}
\State ...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}
\hspace*{-10pt}\framebox[\columnwidth]{\hspace*{15pt}\usebox\mybox\par}
\caption{Language.}
\label{fig:alloy1}
\end{algorithm}
```

The second:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Require $n \geq 0$
\Ensure $y = x^n$
\State $y \gets 1$
\State $X \gets x$
\State $N \gets n$
\While{$N \neq 0$}
\If{$N$ is even}
    \State $X \gets X \times X$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\EndProcedure

\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The main question here would be "Why?" I guess you want to showcase different package outputs? Will this be a small document with just these couple of algorithms?

Comment: One solution is to compile one of the two algorithms in a standalone document (without the surrounding `algorithm` environment) and include the resulting pdf in an `algorithm` environment in your main document using `\includegraphics`. But indeed it would look strange to have two different styles of algorithms in the same document, so it would be better to convert one of the two into the style of the other.

Comment: On a more practical note: the code of your second snippet seems to have a copy-paste mistake, `\end{algorithmic}\end{algorithm}` occurs twice (I suspect the first occurrence should not be there).